# Can't iterate over files within a folder in google cloud notebooks instance

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-ai

I am using the notebooks instance within the AI platform in google cloud console. I have uploaded a folder inside which contains around 30 csv files.

I run the following code to iterate over the files,

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('~/uploadedfiles/'):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        print(filepath)
```

However, for some reason, I can seem to iterate over the files. The cell just ends with no errors. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the ~ with the full path. Python may not do the bash expansion on that tilde:

```
$ cat bork.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/inger.klekacz/parent/'):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        print(filepath)
```

This worked with this dir structure:

```
- parent/
  - foo.txt
  - child1/
    - bar.txt
  - child2/
    - baz.txt
```

like so:

```
$ ./bork.py 
/Users/inger.klekacz/parent/foo.txt
/Users/inger.klekacz/parent/child2/baz.txt
/Users/inger.klekacz/parent/child1/bar.txt
```

But didn't work when I used the tilde.